# Calculate the overall chance of something happening in a trial

Tags: probability

I've searched everywhere for an answer but couldn't find a formula to use.
I have an independent event that has a 1% chance of happening every second. In my trial, there are 30 seconds. How can I calculate the overall chance of this event happening?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  The chance the event happens at least once?  exactly once?

Comment: It won't make any significant *numerical* difference to the answer, but can more than one event happen in a second?

Comment: Yeah at least once. And no, only one event can happen in a second.

Comment: Then the post by David gives the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\eqalign{P(\hbox{event happens at least once})
  &=1-P(\hbox{event does not happen})\cr
  &=1-(0.99)^{30}\ .\cr}$$